# Handle ItemChange event when outlook appointments are dismissed

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I have created some macros to forward my calendar events from my work email to my personal email.  One component is a ItemChange event that will update my personal calendar when items change on my work calendar.  I am having a problem in that every time I dismiss an appointment reminder in outlook it triggers the "itemchange" event.   I am trying to develop something to prevent my item change procedures from running when a reminder is dismissed.  Anyone have an idea how to handle this?   Does anyone know what property of the AppointmentItem changes when a reminder is dismissed?

Comment: welcome to SO. I added `vba` tags because your question concerns vba. That said, please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get the most effective from SO. If you post your code and where you are having trouble implementing your solution you will receive much better help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. When you dismiss a reminder, a couple properties are set and the appointment is saved. A change is a change.

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you know which properties are changed?  Is there a way I could test to see if those properties are what changed, and if so, ignore my ItemChange code?

Comment: Why not do it the other way around? Check the old and new values of the properties that you care about and then decide whether the change can be ignored? You would of course need to store the old values someplace to be able to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I guess ReminderSet is set to False when a Reminder is dismissed.